# Reference could not be added because of same name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

Since the update to VS 2013 I have the behaviour that I cannot add a reference to 2 projects with the same name. I did the following:

1. Added 3 solution folders A, B and C.
2. Added a project of type class library "Core" to both A and B folder.
3. Added a project of type ConsoleApplication to folder C.

The resulting structure looks like this:

```
Solution
 + A
   + Core
 + B
   + Core
 + C
   + ConsoleApp
```

In the project properties of A the following is entered:

- Assembly name: A.Core
- Default namespace: A.Core

and in B:

- Assembly name: B.Core
- Default namespace: B.Core

After I added a reference to A.Core in C.ConsoleApp and I try to reference to B.Core to the console I get the error:

> A reference to 'Core (B.Core)' could not be added. A reference to the component 'Core' already exists in the project.

The solution was created with VS 2012 and shows this behavior since upgrade. What do I have to setup inside the console?

Edit: I published a screencast on [Youtube](http://youtu.be/Fgni6iMfJ-M) to explain the problem and placed a bug at [Microsoft-Support](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809484/bug-when-adding-references-to-projects-with-same-project-names). I still think, this is a bug.

Comment: Hi, has this changed in VS2017?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The issue is that the reference name takes on the project name.  It's still referencing the DLL by the appropriate name (A.Core.dll or B.Core.dll), but the reference uses the project name inside VS:

[image]

If you look at the project file after adding a reference to A.Core, you'll see this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\Core.csproj">
  <Project>{16c42795-f703-4673-98e4-98758c09f9e0}</Project>
  <Name>Core</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Change the Name value to A.Core and you'll be unblocked.  (B.Core will still show up as "Core" until you edit it as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the reposne but this opens a big problem. If you open the same solution in VS 2012, it will work. This means, there is a breaking change in SLN-format which is not reported as far as I know. If I work in 2013 with a project I created in 2012, I'll get problems. But thanks anyway and I mark this as solved.

Comment: Thanks!This saves my day!~

Answer (score 4):

Remove the reference to that dll and then reapply it. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running multiple projects under one roof. Just right click on the main project and add the reference to your new project if you're trying to access new project under the main project.