# Can't add project reference with same name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS2013 solution in which I have the following structure (as an example):

```
My Solution
|-->My Company
|   |--> Common
|-->Common
|-->Web
```

As you can see, I have two projects named "Common" - the one under "My Company" is a company-wide project that is used in all solutions, with a bunch of common code. The other is common code the specific project.

If I try to add both `My Company\Common` and `Common` projects as references to the `Web` project, I get this error message:

[image]

I don't recall this happening in prior versions of Visual Studio. How can I add a reference with the same name (note that the underlying assembly names are not the same).

**Note:** I was able to fix the issue by manually editing the project file and adding a reference to `My Company\Common`. But I'd still like to know why this is happening - is it a bug in VS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference could not be added because of same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150496/reference-could-not-be-added-because-of-same-name)